# How to write multiple excel sheets from a particular column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

This is how df3(pandas dataframe) looks like:

```
        Key        Media_type                                    cleaned_text                                     keyword            subtopic       topic
0    910040          facebook                   will wait outside post office                                 post office               Brand     service
1    910040          facebook                   will wait outside post office                                   will wait              random  irrelevant
2    218658          facebook  there no section post office alabama ups fedex                                 post office               Brand     service
3    218658          facebook  there no section post office alabama ups fedex                                   ups fedex               Brand     service
4    763587           twitter               crazy package delivery rammed car                            package delivery            Shipping     company
5    827572           twitter                  formatting idead delivery done                               delivery done            Shipping     country
6  2404106          facebook           supoused mexico united states america                       united states america            location    marathon
7  1077739           twitter                                          rt ups                                      rt ups             retweet     service
8   786786  extraterristrial                                put one toostamp  (put[a-za-z]{,5}|made|leave)(.{,8})(stamp)  put one's stamp on     outlier
9    36283            unkown                                pute horse stamp  (put[a-za-z]{,5}|made|leave)(.{,8})(stamp)  put one's stamp on     outlier
```

I want to put a filter for each value in df3['subtopic'] and return the resulting values to excel. 
For eg. the manual way of doing it is:

```
df4 = df3.loc[df3['Subtopic'] == 'Brand']
df4.to_excel('subtopic_FedexDriver.xlsx')
```

This is how the output for this piece of code looks like:

```
Key        Media_type                                    cleaned_text                                     keyword            subtopic       topic
0    910040          facebook                   will wait outside post office                                 post office               Brand     service
1    218658          facebook  there no section post office alabama ups fedex                                 post office               Brand     service
2    218658          facebook  there no section post office alabama ups fedex                                   ups fedex               Brand     service
```

I would have to do this for each subtopic individually. 
Is there a way I can automate this? Even if the values are added to different excel sheets within 1 excel file, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('a.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
for n, g in df.groupby('subtopic'):
    g.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=n)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
I keep getting this error when I run the loop for a larger file. Please advise. @ScottBoston

Comment: @YashvardhanRathi  you need to narrow the file down to the particular subtopic.

Comment: Yes I got it working. It was considering all records in the file. I took a sample and did the groupby again and now it looks good. @ScottBoston