# nc file to xlsx conversion with python xarray library

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a .nc file with nearly ~300 million rows. I already transform it to dataframe with pandas "to_dataframe".

I want to transform it to .xslx or .csv file. But excel have [row limit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

When I try the csv solution, data size going up to 5-6 GB (original .nc data size is 400MB). And it is not the cleanest solution.

Maybe I can split the data with excel tabs, but I don't know how to do it easily.

What is the efficient way to do it.

This is my code:

```
import xarray as xr

data = xr.open_dataset('prcp_daily_1948-1948.nc')
df = data.to_dataframe()

df.to_excel('prcp_daily_1948-1948.xlsx')
```

This is the error:

```
ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 316224000, 1 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write multiple excel sheets from a particular column in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309180/how-to-write-multiple-excel-sheets-from-a-particular-column-in-a-pandas-datafram)

Comment: csv is an extremely inefficient storage format - that’s not an xarray problem. There are lots of questions about how to write multiple sheets from pandas to excel. Linked to one above.

Comment: Thanks but slow solution for me.

Comment: yeah - I'd just recommend not doing your analysis on several GBs of data in excel :). There's no fast way to get a large binary array into excel.